# Changing json file format

Tags: python, json, pandas

The script scrapes prices, addresses, suburbs and postcodes of houses and then writes them to a csv file.

The csv file is imported into panda (only postcode and price) and groupby the mean price of the postcode.
This groupby list is written to a json.

The csv file looks like this in excel

```
    ________________________
    |Postcode|Price        |
    ________________________
    |5061    | 205000      |
    ________________________
    |5063    | 930000      |
    ________________________
```

The code looks like this

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame
df = pd.read_csv('House_Prices.csv', usecols=[ 'Postcode' , ' Price' ], index_col=False)

grouped = df.groupby(['Postcode']).mean()

grouped.to_json('average_house_price.json')
```

The code above outputs the json file as

```
{" Price":{"5061":2025000.0,"5063":930000.0}}
```

I want the json file to be outputted like this

```
{"5061":2025000.0,"5063":930000.0}
```

Is there a way with the panda library (or other) to remove the starting Price index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add column name for aggregate `"Price"` or `" Price"` for `Series`:

```
grouped = df.groupby(['Postcode'])["Price"].mean()
#grouped = df.groupby(['Postcode'])[" Price"].mean()

grouped.to_json('average_house_price.json')
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't take the field before saving as JSON, like this:

```py
grouped[" Price"].to_json('average_house_price.json')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try passing **header=None**

Look here:

```
df = pd.read_csv('t.csv', usecols=[ 'Postcode' , ' Price' ], index_col=False, header=None)
```